# Null object from my model returned by view and passed to controller despite entering it in the form

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am writing an MVC5 chat application with entity framework back-end. I have the following code and am getting: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for the line:

```
NewList.Users.Add(User);
```

in

```
public void AddUserToList(UserDetail User, string GroupName)
{
    var collection = from pm in context.GroupUserLists.ToList() select pm;
    foreach (var userList in collection)
    {
        if (GroupName == userList.GroupName)
        {
            userList.Users.Add(User);
            context.Entry(userList).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            return;
        }
    }
    GroupUserLists NewList = new GroupUserLists();
    NewList.GroupName = GroupName;
    NewList.Users.Add(User);
    context.GroupUserLists.Add(NewList);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My view which begins this process is:

```
@model DatabaseDesign.Models.UserDetail

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConnectionId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConnectionId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConnectionId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

And my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddUser(UserDetail User)
{
    var Group = "mikes group";
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserListRepository.AddUserToList(User, Group);
            UserListRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("AddUser");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException dex)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Finally my user model:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int GroupUserListsId { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupUserLists GroupUserLists { get; set; }
}
```

I hope to one day write a tutorial for all this chat system so while I HUGELY appreciate any help in fixing, reasons WHY are just as important.

Edit

db context:
public DbSet GroupUserLists { get; set; }

Comment: Is your GroupUserLists is a data context? and Users is DbCollection? Are you sure that Users is not null in the NewList instance?

Comment: how can it be null though if I'm making it there? Regardless of if UserName or ConnectionId was null, there would still be an object? 
Sorry, didnt notice this comment until now! Wondered why it said "2 answers" on my notification :D

Comment: added context to bottom - unsure what you mean by dbcollection? It generates the UserLists and UserDetail tables during debug. It just wont let me add to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NewList.Users.Add(User);
```

I believe the problem is that the Users object is not initialized. I can't see the constructor for GroupUserLists, but I would imagine it's not initializing the Users collection. This would cause an exception when you tried to add the User object to a collection that isn't initialized.

Comment: thanks, yeah you were right on that i didnt have a constructor for GroupuserLists or UserDetail. Unfortunately I am still gettin the same error. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you set debugger and see if Users property of NewList object is null? If it is you will have to initialize it.

Comment: can you add the constructor code to your question? just because you have a constructor doesn't mean you the list

Comment: Are you getting the error at the same point? There are a couple of other possible NULL references that you could be getting.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry I've been gone all weekend. Yeah I didn't have a constructor initialising the list stupidly. Thank you

Comment: @Josh, where else could this problem persist? "There are a couple of other possible NULL references that you could be getting" - it's not a problem yet but it probably will be... would you mind letting me know where? thanks

Comment: Any of the lists should be checked. It sounds like you probably took care of that with your constructor updates.